# Can I group together dbsets in Entity Framework Core for organization?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework Core, is it possible to put dbsets into a subclass in some way to logically group them together in the code?

So, in C#, instead of:

`context.books`
it could be
`context.library.books`?

Answer (score 3):

It works:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public LibrarySets Library { get; }

    private DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public AppContext() => Library = new LibrarySets(this);

    public class LibrarySets
    {
        private readonly AppContext _appContext;

        public LibrarySets(AppContext context) => _appContext = context;

        public DbSet<Book> Books => _appContext.Books;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=App;Trusted_Connection=true;");
    }
}
```